# Ruby on Rails: ssl_required: how do I enable on the entire app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

Is there an easy way to enable SSL on the entire app?

I'm using rails 2.3.8

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961374/set-ssl-allowed-for-all-pages-in-rails ?

Comment: @Jeff, the post is super old. and teh code has changed since then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, all of your controllers should inherit from `ApplicationController`.

`ssl_required` is actually backed by a protected method called `ssl_required?` which determines whether SSL is required for a given action. This implementation will make SSL always required in the production environment (but not otherwise, so you can still do development as usual).

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # (... other stuff ...)

  protected

  def ssl_required?
    Rails.env.production?
  end
end
```

Depending on your environment, it may also be possible for the upstream server to only be available via HTTPS (e.g. if you're using Apache, you could configure it not to serve your application over port 80). This depends on your server setup.

Comment: doen't you still need to specify what actions to use? even if you redefine the method called by ssl_required?

Comment: ssl_required accepts a list of actions that it stores in an array. The default implementation of ssl_required? simply checks if the current action is in that array. This overrides that to make it apply to all actions, always (well, unless ssl_required? is overridden yet again in a subclass).

Comment: so... how do I invoke ssl_required? globally?

Comment: You don't need to invoke it: it's automatically invoked when Rails tries to run your action. ssl_requirement installs a filter which calls ssl_required? and uses the result to determine whether it should allow the request through or return a redirect to the HTTPS equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 5 you can do this in your application configuration:

So if you want to disable it for your entire application you can just add this to your `config/application.rb`:

```
...
config.force_ssl = true
...
```

Or if you want to configure it differently for different environments:

`config/production.rb`

```
...
config.force_ssl = true
...
```

`config/development.rb`

```
...
config.force_ssl = false
...
```